# Svchost Without services high usage of cpu and ram

Tags: windows, memory

I have a problem on windows 7, there are 2 svchost.exe process that are using each one 200 mb of ram, and one of them is using 50% of the cpu, I tried to kill them but they restart, when I right-click and go to services, there's nothing attached to them,  they only start when I have internet, what can I do? I scanned my pc 2 times with malwarebytes, I already disabled windows update and superfetch

Comment: Use Task Manager details to find what is causing this. Svchost is down near the bottom and you can click on details.  See:  https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/svchost-exe-process-in-windows/

Comment: theres no services associated with the process

Comment: You now need to look at Process Explorer (Microsoft SysInternals).  It is a lot more detailed, but may help you with this.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: Did you look through Process Explorer?  Default shows Memory used and CPU used. Review the high usage.